# MathNet.Numerics Negative Binomial - Median not Calculating

Tags: c#, distribution, mathnet-numerics

I am trying to access the Median property of the Negative Binomial Distribution via MathNet.Numerics;

```
var NegBin = new MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.NegativeBinomial(30, 0.03);
var median = NegBin.Median
```

But I keep getting a `'NegBin.Median' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'`.

Does MathNet.Numerics not calculate the Median here? I am using version 4.9.0.

Comment: https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/e010de79d70f197112cdc86d2e637f5db2968d24/src/Numerics/Distributions/NegativeBinomial.cs

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently not](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/e010de79d70f197112cdc86d2e637f5db2968d24/src/Numerics/Distributions/NegativeBinomial.cs#L158):

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the median of the distribution.
/// </summary>
public double Median => throw new NotSupportedException();
```